# Unlock nokia lumia 630 with smashed screen to access contacts

Tags: lumia, contacts

the title pretty much says it all. 
Is there any app on pc where I can type in my screen pin or something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should find your contacts are synchronised with the primary Microsoft Account that you used when first setting up the phone; So the steps to access them on the phone start with getting the screen fixed, if the handset is hard reset before returning to you, simply set the phone up again with the same account, and all your contacts (and much more if you enabled back-ups prior to the screen being damaged) will be restored.